# liquibase rollback using gradle

Tags: gradle

I've got this databaseChangeLog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
     http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">

<preConditions>
    <dbms type="postgresql"/>
</preConditions>

<changeSet id="rollback1" author="user">
    <tagDatabase tag="version_1.3">
        <createTable tableName="roolback" schemaName="scheme">
            <column name="id" type="int"/>
        </createTable>
        <rollback>
            <dropTable tableName="roolback"/>
        </rollback>
    </tagDatabase>
</changeSet>


</databaseChangeLog>
```

I run `update` in cmd

```
gradle update
```

and it adds table to database.

But how to rollback?
When I do like this

```
gradle rollback -Dliquibase.tag=version_1.3
```

I've got an error - `unexpected value version_1.3: paramters must start with a "--"`

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with plugin 0.7.
When I use plugin 0.6.1 it works fine.
Also I slightly changed .xml

```
<changeSet id="153" author="user">
            <createTable tableName="ToRollback" schemaName="scheme">
                <column name="id" type="int"/>
            </createTable>
            <rollback>
                <dropTable tableName="ToRollback" schemaName="scheme"/>
            </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

And now when I set tags `gradle tag -Dliquibase.tag=230` then `update` database and then make `gradle rollback -Dliquibase.tag=230` it works properly

Answer (score 6):

With liquibase-gradle plugin version 1.2.1, the tag value needs to be passed so:

```
./gradlew rollback -PliquibaseCommandValue="1.3"
```

As per the documentation at https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-gradle-plugin/blob/Release_1.2.1/README.md (refer the last point of the document)